# R rearrange factor levels

Tags: r

I created a data frame using `read.csv(file , header=FALSE)`

My first column has been given an incorrect factor ordering. when i execute `data$V1` the order is correct but the levels are not?

Executing `c(data$V1)` reveals the order is not correct, how can I independently reorder these levels and keep the values in the same location.

Outputs below

```
> data$V1
[1] 0              < 1 in 100000  < 1 in 10000   < 1 in 1000    < 1 in 100     < 1 in 10      > 1 in 10     
Levels: < 1 in 10  < 1 in 100  < 1 in 1000  < 1 in 10000  < 1 in 100000  > 1 in 10  0 
> c(data$V1)
[1] 7 5 4 3 2 1 6
```

Comment: Probably, the function called "reorder" will do it

Comment: so data$V1 <- reorder(data$V1, c(1:7)) ??

Comment: You can test it out to see and/or read the docs at `?reorder`

Comment: Fixed, Can you repost that as an answer please so I can give you the credit for that??

Comment: Ok, gonna see if it's been asked before first. For future reference, it's best to post a reproducible example. Some guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/